# Excel VBA code to trace precedents of cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which traces the precedents of an active cell and spits out a message box with the info. (It also searches for precedents in other worksheets and workbooks).

I am new to VBA, and I would like to request help on changing this code to spit out the precedent cell, formula, and address into a new worksheet after the active worksheet. Please can someone help me understand how to do this.

Should I create a new function to create a new sheet and copy the dynamic info onto it within the first sub?

For example, if I have the formula `A1 + B1` in cell `C1` of Sheet1, then I want a row in Sheet2 (newly created sheet) which shows Target Cell as `C1`, Target Sheet as `Sheet1`, Source Cell as `A1`, and Source Sheet as `Sheet1`. I also want another row in Sheet2 which shows Target Cell as `C1`, Target Sheet as `Sheet1`, Source Cell as `B1`, and Source Sheet as `Sheet1`.

Sheet2:

[image: example]

Code:

```
Option Explicit 
Public OtherWbRefs As Collection 
Public ClosedWbRefs As Collection 
Public SameWbOtherSheetRefs As Collection 
Public SameWbSameSheetRefs As Collection 
Public CountOfClosedWb As Long 
Dim headerString As String 

Sub RunMe() 
    Call FindCellPrecedents(ActiveCell) 
End Sub 

Sub FindCellPrecedents(homeCell As Range) 
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, pointer As Long 
    Dim maxReferences As Long 
    Dim outStr As String 
    Dim userInput As Long 

    If homeCell.HasFormula Then 
        Set OtherWbRefs = New Collection: CountOfClosedWb = 0 
        Set SameWbOtherSheetRefs = New Collection 
        Set SameWbSameSheetRefs = New Collection 

        Rem find closed precedents from formula String 
        Call FindClosedWbReferences(homeCell) 

        Rem find Open precedents from navigate arrows 
        homeCell.Parent.ClearArrows 
        homeCell.ShowPrecedents 
        headerString = "in re: the formula in " & homeCell.Address(, , , True) 
        maxReferences = Int(Len(homeCell.Formula) / 3) + 1 
On Error GoTo LoopOut: 
        For j = 1 To maxReferences 
            homeCell.NavigateArrow True, 1, j 
            If ActiveCell.Address(, , , True) = homeCell.Address(, , , True) Then 
                Rem closedRef 
                Call CategorizeReference("<ClosedBook>", homeCell) 
            Else 
                Call CategorizeReference(ActiveCell, homeCell) 
            End If 
        Next j 
LoopOut: 

        On Error GoTo 0 
        For j = 2 To maxReferences 
            homeCell.NavigateArrow True, j, 1 
            If ActiveCell.Address(, , , True) = homeCell.Address(, , , True) Then Exit For 
            Call CategorizeReference(ActiveCell, homeCell) 
        Next j 
        homeCell.Parent.ClearArrows 

        Rem integrate ClosedWbRefs (from parsing) With OtherWbRefs (from navigation) 
        If ClosedWbRefs.Count <> CountOfClosedWb Then 
            If ClosedWbRefs.Count = 0 Then 
                MsgBox homeCell.Address(, , , True) & " contains a formula with no precedents." 
                Exit Sub 
            Else 
                MsgBox "string-" & ClosedWbRefs.Count & ":nav " & CountOfClosedWb 
                MsgBox "Methods find different # of closed precedents." 
                End 
            End If 
        End If 

        pointer = 1 
        For j = 1 To OtherWbRefs.Count 
            If OtherWbRefs(j) Like "<*" Then 
                OtherWbRefs.Add Item:=ClosedWbRefs(pointer), key:="closed" & CStr(pointer), after:=j 
                pointer = pointer + 1 
                OtherWbRefs.Remove j 
            End If 
        Next j 

        Rem present findings 
        outStr = homeCell.Address(, , , True) & " contains a formula with:" 
        outStr = outStr & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & CountOfClosedWb & " precedents in closed workbooks." 
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & (OtherWbRefs.Count - CountOfClosedWb) & " precedents in other workbooks that are open." 
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Count & " precedents on other sheets in the same workbook." 
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & SameWbSameSheetRefs.Count & " precedents on the same sheet." 
        outStr = outStr & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "YES - See details about Other Books." 
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & "NO - See details about The Active Book." 
        Do 
            userInput = MsgBox(prompt:=outStr, Title:=headerString, Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton3) 
            Select Case userInput 
            Case Is = vbYes 
                MsgBox prompt:=OtherWbDetail(), Title:=headerString, Buttons:=vbOKOnly 
            Case Is = vbNo 
                MsgBox prompt:=SameWbDetail(), Title:=headerString, Buttons:=vbOKOnly 
            End Select 
        Loop Until userInput = vbCancel 
    Else 
        MsgBox homeCell.Address(, , , True) & vbCr & " does not contain a formula." 
    End If 
End Sub 

Sub CategorizeReference(Reference As Variant, Home As Range) 
    Rem assigns reference To the appropriate collection 
    If TypeName(Reference) = "String" Then 
        Rem String indicates reference To closed Wb 
        OtherWbRefs.Add Item:=Reference, key:=CStr(OtherWbRefs.Count) 
        CountOfClosedWb = CountOfClosedWb + 1 
    Else 
        If Home.Address(, , , True) = Reference.Address(, , , True) Then Exit Sub 
        If Home.Parent.Parent.Name = Reference.Parent.Parent.Name Then 
            Rem reference In same Wb 
            If Home.Parent.Name = Reference.Parent.Name Then 
                Rem sameWb sameSheet 
                SameWbSameSheetRefs.Add Item:=Reference.Address(, , , True), key:=CStr(SameWbSameSheetRefs.Count) 
            Else 
                Rem sameWb Other sheet 
                SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Add Item:=Reference.Address(, , , True), key:=CStr(SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Count) 
            End If 
        Else 
            Rem reference To other Open Wb 
            OtherWbRefs.Add Item:=Reference.Address(, , , True), key:=CStr(OtherWbRefs.Count) 
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub 

Sub FindClosedWbReferences(inRange As Range) 
    Rem fills the collection With closed precedents parsed from the formula String 
    Dim testString As String, returnStr As String, remnantStr As String 
    testString = inRange.Formula 
    Set ClosedWbRefs = New Collection 

    Do 
        returnStr = NextClosedWbRefStr(testString, remnantStr) 
        ClosedWbRefs.Add Item:=returnStr, key:=CStr(ClosedWbRefs.Count) 
        testString = remnantStr 
    Loop Until returnStr = vbNullString 

    ClosedWbRefs.Remove ClosedWbRefs.Count 
End Sub 
Function NextClosedWbRefStr(FormulaString As String, Optional ByRef Remnant As String) As String 
    Dim workStr As String 
    Dim start As Long, interval As Long, del As Long 
    For start = 1 To Len(FormulaString) 
        For interval = 2 To Len(FormulaString) - start + 1 
            workStr = Mid(FormulaString, start, interval) 
            If workStr Like Chr(39) & "[!!]*'![$A-Z]*#" Then 
                If workStr Like Chr(39) & "[!!]*'!*[$1-9A-Z]#" Then 
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "#") 
                    interval = interval - 3 * CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) = ":") 
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]") 
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]") 
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]") 
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]") 
                    NextClosedWbRefStr = Mid(FormulaString, start, interval) 
                    Remnant = Mid(FormulaString, start + interval) 
                    Exit Function 
                End If 
            End If 
        Next interval 
    Next start 
End Function 

Function OtherWbDetail() As String 
    Rem display routine 
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & "There are " & OtherWbRefs.Count & " references to other workbooks. " 
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & IIf(CBool(CountOfClosedWb), CountOfClosedWb & " are closed.", vbNullString) 
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & vbCr & "They appear in the formula in this order:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & rrayStr(OtherWbRefs, vbCr) 
End Function 
Function SameWbDetail() As String 
    Rem display routine 
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & "There are " & SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Count & " ref.s to other sheets in the same book." 
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & vbCr & "They appear in this order, including duplications:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & rrayStr(SameWbOtherSheetRefs, vbCr) 
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "There are " & SameWbSameSheetRefs.Count & " precedents on the same sheet." 
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & vbCr & "They are (out of order, duplicates not noted):" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & rrayStr(SameWbSameSheetRefs, vbCr) 
End Function 
Function rrayStr(ByVal inputRRay As Variant, Optional Delimiter As String) 
    Rem display routine 
    Dim xVal As Variant 
    If IsEmpty(inputRRay) Then Exit Function 
    If Delimiter = vbNullString Then Delimiter = " " 
    For Each xVal In inputRRay 
        rrayStr = rrayStr & Delimiter & xVal 
    Next xVal 
    rrayStr = Mid(rrayStr, Len(Delimiter) + 1) 
End Function
```

Comment: that's why I said 'I have the following code' =p haha trying not to reinvent the wheel

Comment: And that's why I put "No need to even work out what your original code is doing!" in my answer. Seemed much easier (and way more fun) to just grab the pre-formatted data from the `MsgBox` :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is best to add two new functions:

1. add the "info sheet" (and store it in a variable for later use)

   ```
   Sub addInfoSheet()
       Dim oldSheet
       Set oldSheet = ActiveSheet
       Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
       Set infoSheet = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index)
       oldSheet.Select
   End Sub
   ```
2. a sub that stores one line to the sheet, something like:

   ```
   Sub addRowToInfoSheet(targetSheet As String, targetRange As String, sourceSheet As String, sourceRange As String)
     infoSheet.Cells(rowInInfoSheet, 1) = targetSheet
     infoSheet.Cells(rowInInfoSheet, 2) = targetRange
     infoSheet.Cells(rowInInfoSheet, 3) = sourceSheet
     infoSheet.Cells(rowInInfoSheet, 4) = sourceRange

     rowInInfoSheet = rowInInfoSheet + 1
   End Sub
   ```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** (v0.2) Now works for all sheets in current workbook. (And fleshed out for other workbooks.)

---

You could do something sneaky and hook the MsgBox function and parse the data from its output.

Just do a global search for `MsgBox` in your code and replace it with, for example, `MsgBoxInterceptor`.

Then you write the `MsgBoxInterceptor()` function, oh, say like the one below ;)

Run the `RunMe()` sub like normal, and voila! Instead of output to the screen, you get output to a new worksheet.

No need to even work out what your original code is doing!

NB The function provided only pulls the precedents from the active workbook.

```
'v0.2
Private Function MsgBoxInterceptor _
                ( _
                           Prompt, _
                  Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, _
                  Optional Title, _
                  Optional HelpFile, _
                  Optional Context _
                ) _
        As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult

  Const i_TargetCell  As Long = 1
  Const i_TargetSheet As Long = 2
  Const i_SourceCell  As Long = 3
  Const i_SourceSheet As Long = 4

  Static slngState As Long
  Static srngDataRow As Range
  Static sstrTargetCell As String
  Static sstrTargetSheet As String
  Static slngClosedBookCount As Long
  Static slngOpenBookCount As Long
  Static slngSameBookCount As Long
  Static slngSameSheetCount As Long

  Dim f As WorksheetFunction: Set f = WorksheetFunction
  Dim lngBegin As Long
  Dim lngEnd As Long
  Dim i As Long

  Select Case slngState
    Case 0: ' Get counts and target
      Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
      Set srngDataRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D1")
      srngDataRow.Value = Split("Target Cell:Target Sheet:Source Cell:Source Sheet", ":")
      Set srngDataRow = srngDataRow.Offset(1)

      lngBegin = InStr(1, Prompt, "]") + 1
      lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, "'")
      sstrTargetSheet = Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin)
      srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetSheet) = sstrTargetSheet

      lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "$") + 1
      lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, " ")
      sstrTargetCell = f.Substitute(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin), "$", "")
      srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetCell) = sstrTargetCell

      lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, ":") + 3
      lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, " ")
      slngClosedBookCount = Val(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin))

      lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, ".") + 2
      lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, " ")
      slngOpenBookCount = Val(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin))

      lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, ".") + 2
      lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, " ")
      slngSameBookCount = Val(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin))

      lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, ".") + 2
      lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, " ")
      slngSameSheetCount = Val(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin))

      slngState = slngState + 1
      MsgBoxInterceptor = vbNo
    Case 1: ' Get same book sources
      lngEnd = InStr(1, Prompt, "[")
      For i = 1 To slngSameBookCount
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetCell) = sstrTargetCell
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetSheet) = sstrTargetSheet

        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "]") + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, "'")
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceSheet) = Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin)

        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "$") + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, Chr$(13))
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceCell) = f.Substitute(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin), "$", "")

        Set srngDataRow = srngDataRow.Offset(1)
      Next i
      For i = 1 To slngSameSheetCount
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetCell) = sstrTargetCell
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetSheet) = sstrTargetSheet

        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "]") + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, "'")
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceSheet) = Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin)

        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "$") + 1
        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, Chr$(13))
        If lngEnd = 0 Then lngEnd = Len(Prompt) + 1
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceCell) = f.Substitute(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin), "$", "")

        Set srngDataRow = srngDataRow.Offset(1)
      Next i
      slngState = slngState + 1
      MsgBoxInterceptor = vbOK
    Case 2: ' Just skipping through
      slngState = slngState + 1
      MsgBoxInterceptor = vbYes
    Case 3: 'Get other book sources (STILL TODO)
      lngEnd = InStr(1, Prompt, "")
      For i = 1 To slngClosedBookCount
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetCell) = sstrTargetCell
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetSheet) = sstrTargetSheet

'        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "]") + 1
'        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, "'")
'        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceSheet) = Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin)
'
'        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "$") + 1
'        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, Chr$(13))
'        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceCell) = f.Substitute(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin), "$", "")

        Set srngDataRow = srngDataRow.Offset(1)
      Next i
      For i = 1 To slngOpenBookCount
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetCell) = sstrTargetCell
        srngDataRow.Cells(i_TargetSheet) = sstrTargetSheet

'        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "]") + 1
'        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, "'")
'        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceSheet) = Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin)
'
'        lngBegin = InStr(lngEnd, Prompt, "$") + 1
'        lngEnd = InStr(lngBegin, Prompt, Chr$(13))
'        If lngEnd = 0 Then lngEnd = Len(Prompt) + 1
'        srngDataRow.Cells(i_SourceCell) = f.Substitute(Mid$(Prompt, lngBegin, lngEnd - lngBegin), "$", "")

        Set srngDataRow = srngDataRow.Offset(1)
      Next i
      slngState = slngState + 1
      MsgBoxInterceptor = vbOK
    Case 4: ' Finished -> tidy up
      srngDataRow.EntireColumn.AutoFit
      slngState = 0
      MsgBoxInterceptor = vbCancel
    Case Else
  End Select

End Function
```

**Explanation:**

The key to this code is the use of static variables, created with the `Static` keyword. These retain their values even after VBA stops running and is restarted. They are used in the code to allow a state machine to be constructed, which mimics a set sequence of user interaction with the message boxes.

The rest is just string parsing of the `MsgBox` messages.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that was great. Could I kindly ask you how can I automate it to continue tracing precedents from the source cells? I need the trace to go all the way back until there is no formula in that cell, and only a hard coded value. I understand that you said this currently will not check for precedents in other worksheets and workbooks, is that correct?

Comment: @Kaitlyn Yes that's correct - it only checks the current sheet. Shouldn't be too hard to expand it to also pull from other worksheets and workbooks. Tracing precedents back to the source is a bit more complicated. Need an extra sub to run through the extracted list, possibly taking care of duplicates, worrying about circular references,etc. This sub would simply call the `RunMe()` sub for every source already found and not traced yet.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** (v0.2) Now displays error messages.

**EDIT:** (v0.3) Now does a full trace back to hard-coded values.

All fun aside, if you're serious about tracing all the way back to a hard-coded value, the best way is to write a main `RunMe_Controller` sub to control the original code. Together with a hook function (and some helper function), this is actually the simplest way to leverage the existing code.

The `MsgBoxInterceptor()` function is smart enough to allow error messages through but silently traps all other `MsgBox()` calls.

See the section at the bottom of the answer for further important details.

**Installation:**

- Copy/paste the ***new bug-fixed*** `RunMe` code block to a module;
- Insert v0.3 of the following updated code block into the previous code where indicated;
- Do a "Current Module", "Find Whole Words Only" search for `MsgBox` with replacement `MsgBoxInterceptor`;
- Add the following two references to the VBA project.

  - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
  - Microsoft Scripting Runtime

**Code:**

```
'===============================================================================
' Module     : <in any standard module>
' Version    : 0.3
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'            : Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' Online     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036068/1961728
'===============================================================================
Private Const l_No_transformation As String = "No transformation"
Private Enum i_
    z__NONE = 0
  SourceCell
  SourceSheet
  SourceBook
  TargetCell
  TargetSheet
  TargetBook
  Formula
  Index
  SourceRef
    z__NEXT
    z__FIRST = z__NONE + 1
    z__LAST = z__NEXT - 1
End Enum
Private meMsgBoxResult As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult
'v0.3
Public Sub RunMe_Controller()

  Const s_Headers   As String = "Source Cell::Source Sheet::Source Book::Target Cell::Target Sheet::Target Book::Formula"
  Const s_Separator As String = "::"
  Const l_Circular  As String = "Circular"

  Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction
  Dim dictFullRefTrace As Scripting.Dictionary  '##Early Bound## As Object
  Dim varRootRef As Variant
  Dim varTargetRef As Variant
  Dim varSavedTraceStepKey As Variant
  Dim varNewTraceStep As Variant
  Dim strNewKey As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Set to true for psychedelic display
  Set dictFullRefTrace = New Dictionary         '##Early Bound## = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  varRootRef = ActiveCell.Address(External:=True)
  dictFullRefTrace.Add varRootRef & s_Separator & s_Separator, TheRefTraceStepAsArray(varRootRef)
  dictFullRefTrace.Add s_Separator & s_Separator, TheRefTraceStepAsArray() 'Need two trace steps in dict to start dynamic expansion
  For Each varSavedTraceStepKey In dictFullRefTrace: Do  ' Can't use .Items as it is not dynamically expanded
    If varSavedTraceStepKey = s_Separator & s_Separator Then ' Dummy trace step (dict exhausted) -> clean up fake trace steps
      dictFullRefTrace.Remove varRootRef & s_Separator & s_Separator
      dictFullRefTrace.Remove s_Separator & s_Separator
      Exit Do
    End If
    varTargetRef = dictFullRefTrace(varSavedTraceStepKey)(i_.SourceRef)
    Select Case True
      Case varTargetRef Like "'?:*": ' Closed Wb -> ignore for now (TODO - auto open it)
        Exit Do
      Case varSavedTraceStepKey Like "*#": ' "No transformation" (from its own trace step) -> ignore
        Exit Do
      Case varSavedTraceStepKey Like "*" & l_Circular: ' "Circular" (from its own trace step) -> ignore
        Exit Do
    End Select
    meMsgBoxResult = vbOK
    FindCellPrecedents Evaluate(varTargetRef) ' ~= RunMe() - leverage the existing code to update the global Ref Collections
    Select Case meMsgBoxResult
      Case vbOK:
        For Each varNewTraceStep In TheNewTraceSteps(fromTarget:=varTargetRef).Items
          strNewKey = varNewTraceStep(i_.SourceRef) & s_Separator & varTargetRef & s_Separator
          If dictFullRefTrace.Exists(strNewKey) Then ' Target is a circular ref -> mark it and then add it
            strNewKey = strNewKey & l_Circular
            varNewTraceStep(i_.Formula) = l_Circular
          End If
          If Not dictFullRefTrace.Exists(strNewKey) Then ' Ignore subsequent circular refs for this target
            dictFullRefTrace.Add strNewKey, varNewTraceStep
          End If
        Next varNewTraceStep
      Case vbIgnore: ' No transformation - typically occurs multiple times, so need multiple unique keys
        varNewTraceStep = TheRefTraceStepAsArray(varTargetRef, varTargetRef)
        strNewKey = varTargetRef & s_Separator & varTargetRef & s_Separator & varNewTraceStep(i_.Index)
        dictFullRefTrace.Add strNewKey, varNewTraceStep
      Case vbAbort: ' Error occurred and message was displayed
        Exit Sub
      Case Else
        ' Never
    End Select
    ' Move dummy trace step to end
    dictFullRefTrace.Remove s_Separator & s_Separator
    dictFullRefTrace.Add s_Separator & s_Separator, vbNullString
  Loop While 0: Next varSavedTraceStepKey
  ' Create, fill and format worksheet
  With Evaluate(varRootRef)
    .Worksheet.Parent.Activate
     Worksheets.Add after:=.Worksheet
  End With
  With ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Resize(ColumnSize:=i_.Index - i_.z__FIRST + 1)
    .Value2 = Split(s_Headers, s_Separator)
    .Font.Bold = True
    With .Offset(1).Resize(RowSize:=dictFullRefTrace.Count)
      .Cells.Value = ƒ.Transpose(ƒ.Transpose(dictFullRefTrace.Items)) ' Fill
      .Sort .Columns(i_.Index), xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    End With
    With .EntireColumn
      .Columns(i_.Formula).Copy
      .Columns(i_.Index).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      .Columns(i_.Formula).Delete
      .Columns(i_.SourceCell).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
      .Columns(i_.TargetCell).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
      .AutoFilter i_.Formula, l_Circular
      .Columns(i_.Formula).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Font.Color = vbRed
      .AutoFilter i_.Formula, l_No_transformation
      .Columns(i_.Formula).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Font.Bold = True
      .AutoFilter
      .Rows(1).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .AutoFit
    End With
    .Cells(1).Select
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Function TheNewTraceSteps _
                 ( _
                   Optional ByRef fromTarget As Variant _
                 ) _
        As Scripting.Dictionary                        '##Early Bound## As Object
        Dim pvarTargetRef As Variant: pvarTargetRef = fromTarget

  Dim mtchMultiCellAddress As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match '##Early Bound## As Object
  Dim strFormula As String
  Dim rngCell As Range
  Dim strKey As String
  Dim astrTraceStep() As String
  Dim varRunMeSourceRef As Variant
  Dim varRefCollection As Variant

  Set TheNewTraceSteps = New Dictionary                '##Early Bound## = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  strFormula = Evaluate(pvarTargetRef).Formula
  With New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp                   '##Early Bound## = CreateObject("VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(?:(?:[:]| *)(?:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\d+:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}\d+))+"
    If .test(strFormula) Then
      For Each mtchMultiCellAddress In .Execute(strFormula)
        For Each rngCell In Evaluate(mtchMultiCellAddress.Value)
          strKey = rngCell.Address
          If Not TheNewTraceSteps.Exists(strKey) Then
            astrTraceStep = TheRefTraceStepAsArray(rngCell.Address(External:=True), pvarTargetRef)
            TheNewTraceSteps.Add strKey, astrTraceStep
          End If
        Next rngCell
      Next mtchMultiCellAddress
    End If
  End With
  For Each varRefCollection In Array(SameWbSameSheetRefs, SameWbOtherSheetRefs, OtherWbRefs)
    For Each varRunMeSourceRef In varRefCollection
      strKey = Evaluate(varRunMeSourceRef).Address
      If Not TheNewTraceSteps.Exists(strKey) Then
        astrTraceStep = TheRefTraceStepAsArray(varRunMeSourceRef, pvarTargetRef)
        TheNewTraceSteps.Add strKey, astrTraceStep
      End If
      varRefCollection.Remove 1
    Next varRunMeSourceRef
  Next varRefCollection

End Function

Private Function TheRefTraceStepAsArray _
                 ( _
                   Optional ByRef SourceRef As Variant = vbNullString, _
                   Optional ByRef TargetRef As Variant = vbNullString _
                 ) _
        As String()

  Static slngIndex As Long ' Required for reverse ordering of trace output

  Dim pvarSourceRef As String: pvarSourceRef = Replace(SourceRef, "''", "'")
  Dim pvarTargetRef As String: pvarTargetRef = Replace(TargetRef, "''", "'")
  Dim astrTraceStepValues() As String: ReDim astrTraceStepValues(1 To i_.z__LAST)
  Dim strFormula As String: strFormula = vbNullString
  Dim astrSourceCellSheetBook() As String
  Dim astrTargetCellSheetBook() As String

  astrSourceCellSheetBook = Ref2CellSheetBook(pvarSourceRef)
  astrTargetCellSheetBook = Ref2CellSheetBook(pvarTargetRef)
  If pvarSourceRef = vbNullString _
  Or pvarTargetRef = vbNullString _
  Then
'    slngIndex = 0 ' Dummy or root ref, i.e., new trace started -> intialize static variable
  Else
    slngIndex = slngIndex + 1
    With Evaluate(TargetRef)
      strFormula = IIf(.HasFormula And pvarSourceRef <> pvarTargetRef, "'" & Mid$(.Formula, 2), l_No_transformation)
    End With
  End If

  astrTraceStepValues(i_.SourceCell) = astrSourceCellSheetBook(1)
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.SourceSheet) = astrSourceCellSheetBook(2)
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.SourceBook) = astrSourceCellSheetBook(3)
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.TargetCell) = astrTargetCellSheetBook(1)
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.TargetSheet) = astrTargetCellSheetBook(2)
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.TargetBook) = astrTargetCellSheetBook(3)
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.Formula) = strFormula
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.Index) = slngIndex
  astrTraceStepValues(i_.SourceRef) = SourceRef
  TheRefTraceStepAsArray = astrTraceStepValues

End Function

Private Function Ref2CellSheetBook(ByRef Ref As Variant) As String()
  Dim × As Long: × = 4
  Dim astrCellSheetBook() As String: ReDim astrCellSheetBook(1 To i_.z__LAST)
  If IsMissing(Ref) Then GoTo ExitFunction:
  × = × - 1: astrCellSheetBook(×) = Mid$(Ref, InStr(Ref, "[") + 1, Abs(InStr(Ref, "]") - InStr(Ref, "[") - 1))
  × = × - 1: astrCellSheetBook(×) = Mid$(Ref, InStr(Ref, "]") + 1, Abs(InStr(Ref, "!") - InStr(Ref, "]") - 2))
  × = × - 1: astrCellSheetBook(×) = Mid$(Ref, InStr(Ref, "!") + 1)
  astrCellSheetBook(×) = Replace(astrCellSheetBook(×), "$", "")
ExitFunction:
  Ref2CellSheetBook = astrCellSheetBook
End Function

Private Function MsgBoxInterceptor _
                ( _
                           Prompt, _
                  Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, _
                  Optional Title, _
                  Optional HelpFile, _
                  Optional Context _
                ) _
        As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult

  If Buttons = vbOKOnly _
  Then
    If Prompt Like "*does not contain a formula*" _
    Or Prompt Like "*contains a formula with no precedents*" _
    Then
      meMsgBoxResult = vbIgnore
    Else
      meMsgBoxResult = vbAbort
      MsgBox Prompt, Buttons, Title, HelpFile, Context
    End If
  End If
  MsgBoxInterceptor = vbCancel
End Function
```

---

**Bug-fixed original code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public OtherWbRefs As Collection
Public ClosedWbRefs As Collection
Public SameWbOtherSheetRefs As Collection
Public SameWbSameSheetRefs As Collection
Public CountOfClosedWb As Long
Dim headerString As String

' <--  Insert other code here

Sub RunMe()
    Call FindCellPrecedents(ActiveCell)
End Sub

Sub FindCellPrecedents(homeCell As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, pointer As Long
    Dim maxReferences As Long
    Dim outStr As String
    Dim userInput As Long

    If homeCell.HasFormula Then
        Set OtherWbRefs = New Collection: CountOfClosedWb = 0
        Set SameWbOtherSheetRefs = New Collection
        Set SameWbSameSheetRefs = New Collection

        Rem find closed precedents from formula String
        Call FindClosedWbReferences(homeCell)

        Rem find Open precedents from navigate arrows
        homeCell.Parent.ClearArrows
        homeCell.ShowPrecedents
        headerString = "in re: the formula in " & homeCell.Address(, , , True)
        maxReferences = Int(Len(homeCell.Formula) / 3) + 1
On Error GoTo LoopOut:
        For j = 1 To maxReferences
            homeCell.NavigateArrow True, 1, j
            If ActiveCell.Address(, , , True) = homeCell.Address(, , , True) Then
                Rem closedRef
                Call CategorizeReference("<ClosedBook>", homeCell)
            Else
                Call CategorizeReference(ActiveCell, homeCell)
            End If
        Next j
LoopOut:

        On Error GoTo 0
        For j = 2 To maxReferences
            homeCell.NavigateArrow True, j, 1
            If ActiveCell.Address(, , , True) = homeCell.Address(, , , True) Then Exit For
            Call CategorizeReference(ActiveCell, homeCell)
        Next j
        homeCell.Parent.ClearArrows

        Rem integrate ClosedWbRefs (from parsing) With OtherWbRefs (from navigation)
        If ClosedWbRefs.Count <> CountOfClosedWb Then '#robinCTS#' Should read (ParsedClosedWbRefs <> CountOfNavigatedClosedWbRefs)
            If ClosedWbRefs.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBoxInterceptor homeCell.Address(, , , True) & " contains a formula with no precedents."
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBoxInterceptor "string-" & ClosedWbRefs.Count & ":nav " & CountOfClosedWb
                MsgBoxInterceptor "Methods find different # of closed precedents."
                End
            End If
        End If

        pointer = 1
        For j = 1 To OtherWbRefs.Count
            If OtherWbRefs(j) Like "<*" Then
                OtherWbRefs.Add Item:=ClosedWbRefs(pointer), Key:="closed" & CStr(pointer), after:=j
                pointer = pointer + 1
                OtherWbRefs.Remove j
            End If
        Next j

        Rem present findings
        outStr = homeCell.Address(, , , True) & " contains a formula with:"
        outStr = outStr & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & CountOfClosedWb & " precedents in closed workbooks."
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & (OtherWbRefs.Count - CountOfClosedWb) & " precedents in other workbooks that are open."
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Count & " precedents on other sheets in the same workbook."
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & SameWbSameSheetRefs.Count & " precedents on the same sheet."
        outStr = outStr & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "YES - See details about Other Books."
        outStr = outStr & vbCr & "NO - See details about The Active Book."
        Do
            userInput = MsgBoxInterceptor(Prompt:=outStr, Title:=headerString, Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton3)
            Select Case userInput
            Case Is = vbYes
                MsgBoxInterceptor Prompt:=OtherWbDetail(), Title:=headerString, Buttons:=vbOKOnly
            Case Is = vbNo
                MsgBoxInterceptor Prompt:=SameWbDetail(), Title:=headerString, Buttons:=vbOKOnly
            End Select
        Loop Until userInput = vbCancel
    Else
        MsgBoxInterceptor homeCell.Address(, , , True) & vbCr & " does not contain a formula."
    End If
End Sub

Sub CategorizeReference(Reference As Variant, Home As Range)
    Rem assigns reference To the appropriate collection
    If TypeName(Reference) = "String" Then
        Rem String indicates reference To closed Wb
        OtherWbRefs.Add Item:=Reference, Key:=CStr(OtherWbRefs.Count)
        CountOfClosedWb = CountOfClosedWb + 1
    Else
        If Home.Address(, , , True) = Reference.Address(, , , True) Then Exit Sub '#robinCTS#' Never true as same check done in caller
        If Home.Parent.Parent.Name = Reference.Parent.Parent.Name Then
            Rem reference In same Wb
            If Home.Parent.Name = Reference.Parent.Name Then
                Rem sameWb sameSheet
                SameWbSameSheetRefs.Add Item:=Reference.Address(, , , True), Key:=CStr(SameWbSameSheetRefs.Count)
            Else
                Rem sameWb Other sheet
                SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Add Item:=Reference.Address(, , , True), Key:=CStr(SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Count)
            End If
        Else
            Rem reference To other Open Wb
            OtherWbRefs.Add Item:=Reference.Address(, , , True), Key:=CStr(OtherWbRefs.Count)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub FindClosedWbReferences(inRange As Range) '#robinCTS#' Should read FindParsedOtherWbReferences
    Rem fills the collection With closed precedents parsed from the formula String
    Dim testString As String, returnStr As String, remnantStr As String
    testString = inRange.Formula
    Set ClosedWbRefs = New Collection

    Do
        returnStr = NextClosedWbRefStr(testString, remnantStr)
        ClosedWbRefs.Add Item:=returnStr, Key:=CStr(ClosedWbRefs.Count)
        testString = remnantStr
    Loop Until returnStr = vbNullString '#robinCTS#' Better if add " Or testString = vbNullString"

    ClosedWbRefs.Remove ClosedWbRefs.Count '#robinCTS#' then this no longer required
End Sub
Function NextClosedWbRefStr(FormulaString As String, Optional ByRef Remnant As String) As String
    Dim workStr As String
    Dim start As Long, interval As Long, del As Long
    For start = 1 To Len(FormulaString)
        For interval = 2 To Len(FormulaString) - start + 1
            workStr = Mid(FormulaString, start, interval)
            If workStr Like Chr(39) & "[![]*[[]*'![$A-Z]*#" Then        '#robinCTS#' Original was "[!!]*'![$A-Z]*#"
                If workStr Like Chr(39) & "[![]*[[]*'!*[$1-9A-Z]#" Then '#robinCTS#' Original was "[!!]*'!*[$1-9A-Z]#" Not required?
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "#") '#robinCTS#' Not required as always Like "*#" here?
                    interval = interval - 3 * CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) = ":")
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]")
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]")
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]")
                    interval = interval - CLng(Mid(FormulaString, start + interval, 1) Like "[$1-9A-Z]")
                    NextClosedWbRefStr = Mid(FormulaString, start, interval)
                    Remnant = Mid(FormulaString, start + interval)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next interval
    Next start
End Function

Function OtherWbDetail() As String
    Rem display routine
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & "There are " & OtherWbRefs.Count & " references to other workbooks. "
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & IIf(CBool(CountOfClosedWb), CountOfClosedWb & " are closed.", vbNullString)
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & vbCr & "They appear in the formula in this order:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    OtherWbDetail = OtherWbDetail & rrayStr(OtherWbRefs, vbCr)
End Function
Function SameWbDetail() As String
    Rem display routine
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & "There are " & SameWbOtherSheetRefs.Count & " ref.s to other sheets in the same book."
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & vbCr & "They appear in this order, including duplications:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & rrayStr(SameWbOtherSheetRefs, vbCr)
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "There are " & SameWbSameSheetRefs.Count & " precedents on the same sheet."
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & vbCr & "They are (out of order, duplicates not noted):" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    SameWbDetail = SameWbDetail & rrayStr(SameWbSameSheetRefs, vbCr)
End Function
Function rrayStr(ByVal inputRRay As Variant, Optional Delimiter As String)
    Rem display routine
    Dim xVal As Variant
    If IsEmpty(inputRRay) Then Exit Function
    If Delimiter = vbNullString Then Delimiter = " "
    For Each xVal In inputRRay
        rrayStr = rrayStr & Delimiter & xVal
    Next xVal
    rrayStr = Mid(rrayStr, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
End Function
```

**Issues:**

- Closed workbooks are not auto-opened (yet)
- Formulas referencing closed workbooks will display the pathname
- Formulas referencing open workbooks *won't* display the pathname, unlike your example
- Only expands simple hard-coded multi-cell ranges (for now)
- Doesn't expand whole columns or rows, yet, only grabs the first cell
- Doesn't find/expand `INDEX`, `OFFSET` or any other similar calculated ranges
- Expanded ranges are not sorted any may not be ordered nicely.

**Features/Enhancements:**

- `RunMe` code bugfixes now allow proper detection of closed workbook refs as requested
- Simple multi-cell ranges now expand out as requested
- Circular references are properly accounted for
- Hard-coded values show a bold "No transformation" as requested
- Hard-coded values display multiple times if accessed from multiple targets
- Apostrophes in sheet names are properly taken care of

> Note: If you are curious about my variable naming convention, it is based on [RVBA](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp).

Comment: Honestly, thank you so much for all your help and advice! I had not done the first part, but it definitely works. I get the output (target and source cells, sheet, and book) on a new sheet, just the way I need. I have a few questions, it still only gives me the first iteration of precedents, and it does not go all the way back to the hard-coded cells of that first initial input cell with formula. Do I have to alter the code in the RunMe_Controller sub where you have said to insert a loop to make it trace all the way back?

Comment: @Kaitlyn That's right. You have to set up a  loop around the entire block. The first time you feed the `With` with `ActiveCell`. Then you loop through the current source cells and feed in those. Then feed in the new source cells. Rinse and repeat. Have a go and see if you can accomplish this. I'm busy right now, but could help out later if you get stuck. Note: this entire comment thread should be moved to chat, but you don't have enough rep for that. We'll just continue here and then clean up when we finish.

Comment: @Kaitlyn Going to bed now (after midnight here). Should have time tomorrow to look at the code, PS If you can post some zipped non-confidential workbooks for me to test on, it would help a bit.

Comment: Hi Robin, Hope you had a good night. I didn't realize you were across the world, haha. Please view the following dropbox link to access the zip file of 3 files I've provided for your reference. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Hi. I found a way to solve some of the issues I was facing above (the long way) by creating new macros to consolidate all the "sheet" outputs into one summary sheet and such. I was kindly wondering if you could help me out with understanding why references to other sheets within the same workbook don't work in the original code. I can manage if it does not trace through other workbooks, but tracing through other sheets in the same workbook is essential for my needs.

Comment: @Kaitlyn Apologies for the delay. Updated the answer with a full working version. Pretty sure I got all the bugs. Still some unresolved issues. Let me know if any are important, or if you find any new ones (or bugs). I'm curious as to how well/ fast it performs on a large sheet set.

Comment: Hey thank you for this. I am getting an error when it gets to "strKey = Evaluate(varRunMeSourceRef).Address"  stopping at this value "=+'C:\BSM-Liqdty\QRM\1 - New ILR Forecast Tool\Actual Files\[CFP for 5-31-2017.xlsx]BankNewRepo.RR Inflow.N&M'!I47"

Comment: Is it possible for us to just ignore the other workbook references at this point? I just want it working for sheets with within the same workbook. Which parts of the code should I comment out please?

Comment: Ok, so i ran it multiple times and tried debugging the issue. Everytime a cell references another workbook, I am getting an error in the code line mentioned above. It is probably because these files are not saved in that "C drive" on my desktop, rather that is the folder of the person who is creating the report. I do not care about other workbook references at this point, I just need the code to work for other sheets within the same workbook. Please can you tell me how to change the code to only get this information?

Comment: hi can you please help me delete all references to other workbook from this code please? I have a need for this code to be up and running today in a few hours. @robinCTS

Comment: @Kaitlyn Add `If Not varRunMeSourceRef Like "+'?:*" Then` before `strKey = Evaluate(varRunMeSourceRef).Address` and `End If` after the next `End If`. That should ignore these non-local external workbooks. Change the string to `"?'?:*"` to disable all external workbooks (and *shouldn't* break anything else).

Comment: @robinCTS regarding special characters: I get the logic of `ƒ`, but what's the motivation for `×`? (And how do you actually type them in the VB Editor?)

Comment: @Egalth If you mean as opposed to using a normal `x`, probably not much. Just like I could have used `f` instead of `ƒ`. Since I use `×` *only* for my special array assignment construct (and `¡` for my generic looping variable), and these are the *only* less than about 6 character variables I ever use, I figured they deserved to be special ;) As for entering them, I *could* have memorized the Alt-Numeric keyboard shortcuts, but instead I have the declarations stored as a function and a sub template. which I copy/paste…

Comment: Then, I use `Ctrl`+`Space` followed by `Down` once or twice followed by `Space` for `×` and `¡`. For `ƒ` I use `f`,`Ctrl`+`Space` then `Up` a few times followed by `Space`.