# VBA to capture target of linked cell

Tags: excel, vba

`A1` is a cell containing a link to `B1` on another sheet (ie `=Sheet2!B1`).

How do I get VBA to copy the target of A1 rather than create a link to A1 itself?
I want the output to be `=Sheet2!B1` rather than `=A1`, but I have to go through `A1` to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "output"?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear - say the result is to be put into another cell, eg. C1. This would be the output.

Comment: Sorry to not follow, what would be put in another cell? Why the VBA tag? What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Use [`Range.Precedents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents)

Comment: @ScottCraner - for some reason `Precedents` didn't seem to work when I tested (the cell had no precedents, tested both programmatically and with GoTo > Special). Though one could just do `Range("C1").Formula = Range("A1").Formula` here, IIUC.

Comment: Yup, apparently it only works when the precedent is on the same sheet.

Comment: Here is a good work around: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/

Comment: It might help to explain what you're doing and why `=A1` can't work here.

Comment: An SO answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025869/excel-vba-code-to-trace-precedents-of-cell   Haven't tested it but looks like what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW - I got the target address by storing it on creation and used this:

ws.range("C1").Formula = "=sheet2!" & "B" & X

Answer (score 0):

can you test this? Get your value in cell A1 from wherever, and save that into a variable, then you can place that variable in any cell. Hope I understood your question!

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim snip As String

snip = Range("A1")
Range("C10") = snip

End Sub
```